# PHP SoapClient type mapping behaves differently

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I've a web-service function which is returning an array of items to a PHP-Client. Depending on the number of items, the PHP return type is differently. If the function returns one item the PHP type is `stdClass` if the function returns more than one item, the PHP type is `array`. In either case it should be `array`. What can I do to achieve this?

#### Details:

A `var_dump` of the result from the web-service function looks like following:

- if one item is in the result:
  `array(3) { ["filterErg"]=> object(stdClass)#37 (1) { ["item"]=> object(stdClass)#38 (9) ...`
- if more than one item is in the result:
  `array(3) { ["filterErg"]=> object(stdClass)#37 (1) { ["item"]=> array(16) ...`

The name of the function is `getFilter` and the relevant parts of the WSDL File are:

```
<types>
  <schema ...>
    <complexType name="arrayFilter">
      <sequence>
        <element name="item" type="ns1:stFilter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
    ...
  </schema>
</types>

<message name="getFilterResponse">
  <part name="filterErg" type="ns1:arrayFilter"/>
  <part name="functionResult" type="xsd:int"/>
  <part name="outErr" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>

<portType name="ADServicePortType">    
  <operation name="getFilter">
    <documentation>Service definition of function ns1__getFilter</documentation>
    <input message="tns:getFilter"/>
    <output message="tns:getFilterResponse"/>
  </operation>
  ...
</portType>

<binding name="ADService" type="tns:ADServicePortType">
  <SOAP:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="getFilter">
    <SOAP:operation style="rpc" soapAction=""/>
    <input>
      <SOAP:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:ADService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </input>
    <output>
      <SOAP:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:ADService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </output>
  </operation>
  ...
</binding>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the variable from object to an array containing the object on occasion:

```
if (is_object($variable))
{
    $variable = array($variable);
}
```

Or more specifically in your case:

```
if (is_object($result["filterErg"]->item))
{
    $result["filterErg"]->item = array($result["filterErg"]->item);
}
```

Comment: Simple and practical solution, many thanks! I was blind for that because I focused on changing the web-service interface.

Answer (score 8):

You can use SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS option when you are creating SoapClient

```
$soapConfig = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
    'trace'    => true
);
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8070/Services.wsdl', $soapConfig);
```