# How to "normalize" a php Object from SoapClient with inconsistent structure?

Tags: php, oop

I have a php stdObject that is an object, and sometimes an array of Objects.

**EDIT:** It's been returned by `SoapClient::__soapCall`.

If it has one entry:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Event] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Nr] => 7050
            [Date] => 2016-11-30T00:00:00
        )

)
```

If it's got multiple entries:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Event] => Array
        (
         [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Nr] => 7015
                    [Date] => 2016-04-28T00:00:00
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Nr] => 7016
                    [Date] => 2016-04-29T00:00:00
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Nr] => 7017
                    [Date] => 2016-06-08T00:00:00
                )
        )
)
```

I don't see why, and I'd like to correct it.

Here's how I got there:

```
$items = $this->getAll(); // returns an Object with n entries
foreach($items as $item){
    $fullItem = $this->item->getElementByID($item->Nr); // returns the full data for this entry
    $item->Days = $fullItem->Days; // that's the one that can contain objects or just the data if it has one entry
}
```

My Questions:

- Is that normal, that the same request returns different data types?
- Should I "normalize" this and make an array of objects if there's only one entry?
- Or is there an other recommended way to cope with it?

Comment: I'd say it's pretty normal depending on your data source. Usually, a collection of items should be returned if many are requested, but skip the collection if only one is specified. If the data source is some sort of out-sourced end-point the same request could yield different types of objects depending on parameters. I.e `GET /store` might return all store items, while `GET /store/1` would return a single item with id 1.

Comment: Incongruent? I believe inconsistent is a better word for it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's ok in this case. You should keep the interface the same. So if you are expecting an unknown number of elements it should always be a collection, even if in some cases only one element is returned. However if you expect only one element then the collection should be omitted.

```
$this->getAll(); //should always return a collection
$this->getOneById($id); //should return single item without collection, return null or throw exception if no element is found
```

On the question should you "normalize" (refactor) it I wold say it depends on the effort estimation and the benefit you'll gain form the refactoring. If this occurs in few places only and it's not likely to be used in any other place in the future I think you shouldn't bother. In case you decide to refactor be very careful and ensure the whole application is working properly. If you have tests - great.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've given a more detailed look to where I get that data from and will add it as an answer

Comment: The answer is right – it's not ok. The solution for my special case with the SOAP Client is in my own answer

Answer (score 0):

I didn't declare it in the question, sorry: The data is the result of a soap client call:

```
 $this->soapClient = new \SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array('trace' => DEBUG_SOAP));
 // ...
 $result = $this->soapClient->__soapCall($method, array($method => $params));
```

I think what confused me is the standard behaviour of `SoapClient::__soapCall`

> SOAP functions may return one, or multiple values. If only one value
>   is returned by the SOAP function, the return value of __soapCall will
>   be a simple value (e.g. an integer, a string, etc). If multiple values
>   are returned, __soapCall will return an associative array of named
>   output parameters.

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Also, a very similar question: [PHP SoapClient type mapping behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408283/php-soapclient-type-mapping-behaves-differently)

And here are two solutions from there:

"Normalize" (what's the correct word?) the data AFTER we got it:

```
if (is_object($variable)){
    $variable = array($variable);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6408780/160968

And, that would be the equivalent to refactoring the request BEFORE we get it – **there's a setting for the soapClient!**

```
$soapConfig = array(
    'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
    'trace'    => true
);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapConfig);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8008715/160968

Awesome!